# Streamreader and "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, streamreader

I didn't write any array length but when i try to read .csv file i get the **"Index was outside the bounds of the array"** error. .csv file is about 1 000 000 line. Is there anyone to fix this code?

.csv file lines are like below.

> 0000000,26.0000000000000,38.0000000000000,30.01.2017,0,0,0,,,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0

```
string[] read;
char[] seperators = { ',' };


        try
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile(txtFilePath.Text); 
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            pictureBox1.Image = img;
            pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(txtFile2Path.Text);

            string data;

            while ((data=sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
            {
                read = data.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);

                float x = float.Parse(read[1]);
                float y = float.Parse(read[2]);
                string z = read[10];
            }
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: In debug mode look at this lines `float x = float.Parse(read[1]);
                float y = float.Parse(read[2]);string z = read[10];`

Comment: You may want to have an if condition if read.Length >= 11

Comment: There is no error in these lines in debug mode. Everythings looks correct in visual studio in debug mode.

Comment: This is runtime error, put breakpoint on this lines and check if there `read.Length >= 11` as @Ben said

Comment: if condition with read.Length >= 11 works with the code. Thanks you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify the answer for anyone that ends up here..

```
        while ((data=sr.ReadLine()) !=null)
        {
            read = data.Split(seperators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (read.Length >= 11)
            {
                float x = float.Parse(read[1]);
                float y = float.Parse(read[2]);
                string z = read[10];
            }
        }
```

When accessing an array that may not be the desired length, check it first.

An `Index was outside the bounds of the array` exception will only be thrown when a line of code is trying to access an item (N-1) in the array that does not exist - due to the array having less than (N) items